# Qt. Windows. Приложение крашится при запуске

Tags: windows, qt

Имеется QML приложение на Qt 5.13. Из Qt Creator-а стартует без проблем. 
Но после деплоя крашится.
Выполняю следующие команды:

```
windeployqt.exe --quick ./
```

а затем

```
windeployqt --qmldir D:\sources D:\build\release\bin.exe
```

При этом ошибок не возникает.

Но приложение не запускается, вылетая с ошибкой "**Ошибка при запуске приложения (0xc000007b**)"

Причем данная проблема свойственна только при сборке под x32. Версия x64 не крашится.

До этого использовал Qt версии 5.11 и точно таким же образом все работало.
Дело не в конкретном проекте. Для достоверности, я попробовал задеплоить новое пустое приложение - ошибка та же.

Прежде чем установить новую версию Qt(5.13) я удалил старую через maintenance Tools и удалил сам каталог. В переменных окружения ничего связанного с Qt нет.

Comment: Очень много причин, от драйверов видеокарты, до актуальных C++ библиотек.

Comment: @biggiemot единственное изменение в системе - обновление Qt до версии 5.13.

Comment: @biggiemot 2017. Кстати появилась еще одна деталь. Если собрать приложение под x64, то работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, ты использовал windeployqt из другого комплекта, из-за этого разрядность подставляемых библиотек (x64) не совпадает с разрядностью бинарника (x32). Запускай windeployqt из-под ярлыка, наименование которого соответствует целевому комплекту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]